# Ordering one-to-many models in Flask sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to write a specific query that allow users to refine their search. I have a one-to-many relationship between Authors and Books:

```
class Author(Model):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    books = relationship('Book', backref='author', lazy='dynamic')

class Book(Model):
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = Column(String)
    pages = Column(Integer, default=0)
    is_published = Column(Boolean, default=False)
    author_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('author.id'))
```

How can I build the appropriate query in Flask sqlalchemy that answers this question:

"**Give me all authors that have at least one published book and sort all authors by the number of pages in their books from shortest to longest.**"

I'm thinking that the authors will be sorted only by their shortest book, regardless if they have another book that is much longer.

An example:

```
Bob
   book A: 62 pages, published
   book B: 10 pages, published

Alice 
   book C: 100 pages, published
   book D: 1 pages, published

Carol
   book E: 3 pages, NOT-published
   book F: 1000 pages, published

Eve
   book G: 2000 pages, NOT-published
```

The query would return authors in this order:

```
  [ Alice, Bob, Carol ]
```

Because Alice has the shortest published book (1 page), Bob has the second shortest published book (10 pages), and Carol has the longest (1000 pages). Eve does not get mentioned because she does not have any published books.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
session.query(Author)
    .join(Author.books)
    .filter(Book.is_published == True)
    .group_by(Author.id)
    .order_by(func.min(Book.pages))
```

Comment: What would be the opposite (highest to lowest)? I tried `func.max()` but for some reason that still returns the min.

Comment: If you want to flip the order by, you can use `desc(func.min(Book.pages))`